Question about the residue theorem. How to deal with removable and essential singularities?
I am reading the Complex Analysis by Stein:

In the book, the Residue Theorem has a strong assumption that all the singularities should be poles ( in fact, the residue is defined for poles ) within the contour and the proof of the theorem highly reliable on the locally behavior of a pole, i.e. it can be expanded as a principal part plus a holomorphic function. ( See details from the book below ).
If $\operatorname{f}$ has a pole of order $n$ at $z_{0}$, then
$$
\operatorname{f}\left(z\right) =
\frac{a_{-n}}{\left(z - z_{0}\right)^{n}} +
\frac{a_{-n + 1}}{\left(z - z_{0}\right)
^{n - 1}} +
\cdots + \frac{a_{-1}}{z - z_{0}} +
\operatorname{G}\left(z\right)
$$
where $\operatorname{G}$ is a holomorphic function in a neighborhood of $z_{0}$.
The sum
$$
\frac{a_{-n}}{\left(z - z_{0}\right)^{n}} +
\frac{a_{-n + 1}}{\left(z - z_{0}\right)
^{n - 1}} +
\cdots + \frac{a_{-1}}{z - z_{0}}
$$
is called the principal part of $\operatorname{f}$ at the pole $z_{0}$, and the coefficient $a_{-1}$ is the residue of $\operatorname{f}$ at that pole.
Therefore, if $\operatorname{P}\left(z\right)$ denotes the principal part above and $C$ is any circle centered at $z_{0}$, we get
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi{\rm i}}\oint_{C}\operatorname{P}\left(z\right) {\rm d}z = a_{-1}
$$


My question is how to deal with other types of singularities ?. What is the definition of residue for them ?. Why is the residue for a removable singularity zero ?. How to prove the residue theorem with other types of singularities ?.

I found many using Laurent series but do not find a satisfied answer compatible to the logic of the book.

Residue at $z_0$ is always the coefficient of $\frac  1{z-z_0}$ in the power/Laurent series expansion around $z_0$.

What would you recommend me to read if I want to build a consistent understanding of what is going on with my existent knowledge (mainly the mateiral from Stein's book)?

Rudin's RCA is an excellant book.
